# Common Crypto -- Testing for bad key in decryption?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography, commoncrypto

I have written up code that makes use of iOS's Common Crypto to encrypt and decrypt an `NSData` object.  The encryption keys are AES128, and are stored in the iOS keychain.  I can encrypt and decrypt the data successfully, so I know that portion of code is working.  As a sanity check, however, I've also generated a *second* AES128 key and attempted to decrypt data that was encrypted with the *first* encryption key.  I was expecting the `CCCryptorStatus` value to be something other than `kCCSuccess`, however this was not the case.  I received back an `NSData` object and no error.  My encrypt/decrypt code looks something like this...

```
-(NSData *)dataDecryptedUsingAlgorithm:(CCAlgorithm)algorithm
                                  data:(NSData *)data
                                   key:(id)key
                  initializationVector:(id)iv
                               options:(CCOptions)options
                                 error:(CCCryptorStatus *)error {
    CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

    NSParameterAssert([key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [key isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);
    NSParameterAssert(iv == nil || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);

    NSMutableData * keyData, * ivData;
    if ( [key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] )
        keyData = (NSMutableData *) [key mutableCopy];
    else
        keyData = [[key dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];

    if ( [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] )
        ivData = [[iv dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
    else
        ivData = (NSMutableData *) [iv mutableCopy];    // data or nil

    //    [keyData autorelease];
    //    [ivData autorelease];

    // ensure correct lengths for key and iv data, based on algorithms
    FixKeyLengths( algorithm, keyData, ivData );

    status = CCCryptorCreate( kCCDecrypt, algorithm, options,
                             [keyData bytes], [keyData length], [ivData bytes],
                             &cryptor );

    if ( status != kCCSuccess )
    {
        if ( error != NULL )
            *error = status;
        return ( nil );
    }

    NSData *result = [self runCryptor:cryptor onData:data result:&status];
    if ( (result == nil) && (error != NULL) )
        *error = status;

    CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);

    return ( result );
}

-(NSData *)dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm:(CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                  data:(NSData *)data
                                   key:(id)key
                  initializationVector:(id)iv
                               options:(CCOptions)options
                                 error:(CCCryptorStatus *)error {
    CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

    NSParameterAssert([key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [key isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);
    NSParameterAssert(iv == nil || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);

    NSMutableData * keyData, * ivData;
    if ( [key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] )
        keyData = (NSMutableData *) [key mutableCopy];
    else
        keyData = [[key dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];

    if ( [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] )
        ivData = [[iv dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
    else
        ivData = (NSMutableData *) [iv mutableCopy];    // data or nil

    //    [keyData autorelease];
    //    [ivData autorelease];

    // ensure correct lengths for key and iv data, based on algorithms
    FixKeyLengths( algorithm, keyData, ivData );

    status = CCCryptorCreate( kCCEncrypt, algorithm, options,
                             [keyData bytes], [keyData length], [ivData bytes],
                             &cryptor );

    if ( status != kCCSuccess )
    {
        if ( error != NULL )
            *error = status;
        return ( nil );
    }

    NSData *result = [self runCryptor:cryptor onData:data result:&status];
    if ( (result == nil) && (error != NULL) )
        *error = status;

    CCCryptorRelease( cryptor );

    return ( result );
}

-(NSData *)runCryptor:(CCCryptorRef)cryptor onData:(NSData *)data result:(CCCryptorStatus *)status {
    size_t bufsize = CCCryptorGetOutputLength( cryptor, (size_t)[data length], true );
    void * buf = malloc( bufsize );
    size_t bufused = 0;
    size_t bytesTotal = 0;
    *status = CCCryptorUpdate( cryptor, [data bytes], (size_t)[data length],
                              buf, bufsize, &bufused );
    if ( *status != kCCSuccess )
    {
        free( buf );
        return ( nil );
    }

    bytesTotal += bufused;

    // From Brent Royal-Gordon (Twitter: architechies):
    //  Need to update buf ptr past used bytes when calling CCCryptorFinal()
    *status = CCCryptorFinal( cryptor, buf + bufused, bufsize - bufused, &bufused );
    if ( *status != kCCSuccess )
    {
        free( buf );
        return ( nil );
    }

    bytesTotal += bufused;

    return ( [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: buf length: bytesTotal] );
}
```

When I call the encrypt and decrypt methods, I am passing in `kCCAlgorithmAES128` as my algorithm, and `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` as my options.  Is there a way to catch when a bad key is used for decryption so I can return the appropriate error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way to distinguish between a bad key and corrupted data is, as Zaph notes, some kind of crib (i.e. used in the broadest sense of the term; i.e. something you know about the encryption). If you're interested in an approach to this, see the [RNCryptor v4 spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/draft-RNCryptor-Spec-v4.0.md). There is no implementation of this yet, it's just a spec, but it includes a validator field that can be used to determine whether the password is correct. It uses an HKDF-Expand step that converts some of your initial keying material into a validation token.

---

As a note, this part of your method is quite concerning:

```
if ( [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] )
    ivData = [[iv dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
 else
    ivData = (NSMutableData *) [iv mutableCopy];    // data or nil
```

If a string is passed in, this has a dramatically smaller keyspace than you may expect. Even if it is 16 totally random bytes of string, legal UTF8 strings represent a much smaller space than an equivalent 16 bytes of random data.

Comment: Personally I like KCV's (key check values) as they give you some indication what could be wrong. But a KCV may also become corrupted, so you still cannot distinguish between a bad key and corrupted data. See also my question [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1930/1172). Note that your protocol uses a KCV and a MAC - just adding the KCV is not enough, you should make that clear in your answer.

Comment: Since I was already using HKDF-Expand to generate other keying materials, it seemed natural to continue the process and use it to generate the validator. I'd be happy to hear any suggested improvements on the format, though. While it's true that the validator (or KCV) could itself be corrupted, it still represents a significant benefit for large messages which could take substantial time to HMAC-validate, and for which corruption outside the validator is much more likely (but wrong password is even *more* likely). The validator is also unambiguous if it checks-out but the HMAC fails.

Comment: I'm happy with the validation token. And yes, using a KDF for creating the validation token is an obviously good idea, and then I would certainly choose HKDF myself. Validation token is a better name than KCV as the calculation does not directly involve the key itself.

Comment: Outstanding advice!  My crypto background is on the Java platform, so I was more concerned with how crypto is handled on iOS.  I'll be sure to take a look at RNCrypto.  Looks like a very well thought out project.

Comment: Note that there are several existing implementations for the v3 file format, including in Java. That format doesn't include a password-validator, though. You can't tell the difference between bad password and corrupt message (though it's usually a bad password).

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot unless you use a cipher mode that adds authentication such as GCM or EAX mode of operation. Otherwise there is always the odd chance that decryption will return success as the padding may be correct after decryption. In other words, you cannot use the `CCCryptorStatus` to (reliably) detect incorrect keys or corrupted ciphertext. As Zaph has noted by pointing to [a discussion on the Apple forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/920949#920949), `CCCryptorStatus` may never be set to `kCCDecodeError` for newer versions of iOS (6 and 7) because of the possibility of padding Oracle attacks.

Instead of using a cipher that adds authentication you can also add your own authentication tag, e.g. by calculating a HMAC value over the ciphertext. It's best to use a second key for HMAC and to include the IV in the authenticated data. Note that you need to check the authentication tag *before* you use the plaintext or decrypt the last block (in CBC mode encryption). Otherwise you will be vulnerable to padding oracle attacks.

Note that you will not be able to fully distinguish between an incorrect key and corruption of the ciphertext.

Comment: PS only glanced over your code, so don't count this as a full review.

Comment: It specifically doesn't distinguish between those two cases.

Comment: @Zaph I never said that it is an indicator, but I edited the question to explicitly address your concern.

Comment: Based on an extended discussion on the Apple Development Forum it appears that `CCCryptor` does not currently return bad `CCCryptorStatus` if there is incorrect padding but at one time did. It is just not reliable for a check on incorrect decryption.

Comment: @Zaph Could you point to that discussion, as the `CCCryptorFinal` explicitly specifies: "`kCCDecodeError` Indicates garbled ciphertext or the wrong key during decryption. This **can** only be returned while decrypting with padding enabled."

Comment: [CCCrypt always return kCCSuccess](https://devforums.apple.com/message/920949#920949). In particular look at 3. This is not the only occurrence of this issue in the forums, just the most succinct.

Comment: @Zaph Cannot log in, so I cannot check, but it wouldn't invalidate "In other words, you cannot use the CCCryptorStatus to (reliably) detect incorrect keys or corrupted ciphertext." would it?

Comment: "Enforcement of kCCDecodeError was removed". How can you argue about a post you have not seen?

Comment: Read the discussion. That's quite a stupid fix by Apple (it will fail on content instead, which is just as detectable if it is returned to the sender), but I'll make the warning *that you cannot reliably detect incorrect keys or ciphertext* **even** more specific.

Comment: @owlstead OK, you asked for the thread, I provided it, you read it, the answer was concise, a security reason was given, the source is ultra reliable. It is clear that `kCCDecodeError` can not be used. You do agree with that, correct? Now the argument takes a turn that Apple made a bad decision? That is not the question, the question is about what is implemented by Apple. (Correct your answer and I will up-vote it).

Comment: @Zaph No, that's just a statement about this fix by Apple, nothing to do with my answer. Already corrected it.

Comment: I still see: "Otherwise there is always the odd chance that decryption will return success as the padding may be correct after decryption. In other words, you cannot use the CCCryptorStatus to (reliably) detect incorrect keys or corrupted cipher text." Othjer than this statement you have a good answer. In fact one can not use CCCryptorStatus to detect incorrect keys or corrupted cipher text. (notice the deletion).

Comment: I've put the fix below that. Note that according to the documentation, and apparently on older platforms, you may still get the error message (and it is true in the general sense as well, e.g. Windows API's and Java will simply return an error *if* a padding error is detected). So if you don't mind, I keep that statement only to refute it later on.

Comment: No problem, I don't mind. I will vote based on what I believe to be a good and correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially there is no way to know if a message is correctly or incorrectly decrypted. As far as AES (as well as most encryption) is concerned it is just bits in and bits out. This is a feature.

The error `CCCryptorStatus` only handles gross errors. It does not set kCCDecodeError for incorrect padding, this has been discussed at length on the Apple Developer Forums.

Determining if a decryption is correct was a major problem back in WWII with decryption. Essentially a "Crib" was needed, some portion of the message that was known to test a decryption against. From Wikipedia: The term "crib" originated at Bletchley Park, the British World War II decryption operation.

If you want that you need to add that to the protocol you are using for communications.

Comment: Using a "Crib" was maybe a good idea in WW2, but not anymore. Authentication tags (authenticated encryption, MAC or HMAC) is now.

Comment: A "Crib" was used to indicate that decryption might have succeeded. It was knowledge of a part of the message such as a standard prefix or salutation. It was **not** authentication.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with it. With just a crib the ciphertext is vulnerable to padding oracle attacks. If it is too small then an attacker could try until you get the right crib. And that's just the start of the problems...

Comment: @owlstead Perhaps you misunderstand what a Crib is and what it is used for. A Crib is **not** used to create security, it is used to **break** encryption. See [Known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack), that is a Crib.

Comment: You know, I used to hold your answers and comments in high esteem but rather it seems you are argumentative, not willing to give up flogging a dead horse. Note, the whole crib thing is historic perspective (WWII).

Comment: And hence you now downvote my answer, perform an ad hominem attack, and defend you own answer indicating that is placed here for [historical reasons](http://history.stackexchange.com/), instead of refuting my arguments in any logical sense.

Comment: I down voted you're answer because it contains some misleading information WRT CCCryptorStatus which is the crux of the OP's question. Yes, I do believe that you are being argumentative and that is not an ad hominem attack but a comment about your actions here, see above, but I may be wrong. And yes, I did hold you in high regard.